# Fallback to deprecated methods in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, events, callback

I have a third party service that's pulling in one of our JS files from our main site. The reason for this is to make various pieces in the header and footer work (they are duplicated from our main site). The third party service uses an incredibly old version of jQuery which causes the `.on()` method calls to fail. I'm trying to write something to detect this and switch over to deprecated methods. What I have now works just fine (we're only using click events in this file...for now):

```
if(!$.isFunction($.fn.on)) {
    $.fn.on = $.fn.click;
}
```

I'd like to make the above work for ANY event so that in our main file we can still use the same `.on()` method that newer versions of jQuery incorporate without breaking the third party application. What I've tried doesn't work:

```
if(!$.isFunction($.fn.on)) {
    $.fn.on = function(event, callback) {
        return $.fn[event](callback());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just use .bind, it's available in all versions of jquery and should continue to be available.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I had read that it was deprecated. Guess I should have checked the official jQuery API first. Just to learn I'd still like to know how to accomplish the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing your callback too early.

```
if(!$.isFunction($.fn.on)) {
    $.fn.on = function(event, callback) {
        return $.fn.bind.call(this,arguments);
    }
}
```

This is also missing many of the different ways of using .on, but it would take a good bit to actually make that work without just copying the source of .on.

You really shouldn't be doing this at all though, it could cause other oddities with the existing page that you can't predict, therefore i'd suggest just using `.bind`. directly since it exists in all versions of jQuery and will continue to exist for backwards compatibility.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks again for giving me the correct information on bind()